# Error accesing Geography data: OutOfMemoryException Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SridList

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlgeography

I'm getting a weird error on my site, up until this point everything was ok, now I get this error everytime I access a page that queries data that contains geography data (from what I can tell) . I can query all the data in Microsoft SQL Studio though...
I have a second website wit the exact same on code on same server but with different databases, and that one works ok. The SQL server database of the one that does not work has available space of 6MB, and the other that does work has 60MB available.  The autogrowth is set to 64MB

Any idea on what I can fix this?  Below is the stack trace:

> [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
> was thrown.]    Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SridList..cctor() +0
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SridList' threw an exception.]
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.set_Srid(Int32 value) +26
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
> +52    lambda_method(Closure , BinaryReader ) +140    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlSpatialDataReader.GetGeography(Int32
> ordinal) +216
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +232    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetSpatialPropertyValueWithErrorHandling(Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName, PrimitiveTypeKind spatialTypeKind) +328    lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +7306    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2
> constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
> +258    lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +518    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +384    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MaterializeRow() +137    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.<MoveNextAsync>d__7.MoveNext() +355    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.<TryReadToNextElementAsync>d__12.MoveNext() +360    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.<MoveNextAsync>d__a.MoveNext() +369    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    System.Data.Entity.Internal.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +614   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext() +379
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +62    Repository.Pattern.Ef6.d__f.MoveNext() +327
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +62    Repository.Pattern.Ef6.d__0.MoveNext() +320
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +62
> BeYourMarket.Web.Controllers.d__af.MoveNext() +2254
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +62    BeYourMarket.Web.Controllers.d__9c.MoveNext()
> +203    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +62
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +92
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +22
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +69
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
> +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
> +396    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +69
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
> +38    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +188
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +59
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +32
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +39    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +59
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +46
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +73
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> +59    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
> +231    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
> ar) +172

Comment: I think you would probably be good to just show the first fewones of the error.

Comment: This looks like an error happening in the client - not being thrown by SQL Server

Comment: Post the code that raises this error. OOM exceptions are typically thrown when the *application code* uses memory inefficiently, causing so much memory fragmentation that the runtime can't find a large enough chunk of memory any more. Adding eg 1M items to a list will cause a huge fragmentation. `Repository.Pattern.Ef6` is a pretty strong smell - a DbContext already is a high level, generic, multi-entity Unit-of-Work and Repository, it doesn't need to be wrapped in a low-level CRUD class. Does the CRUD class have a GetAll method that loads an entire table in memory perhaps?

Comment: It's also possible that the `geography` value is big and the existing memory fragmentation prevented the runtime from finding a memory chunk that can hold the geography. The fact SSMS works doesn't say much - the application only loads the first 65KB from large non-XML fields in the grid.

Comment: @DaleK the first few lines would hide this is thrown by a "Repository.Pattern.Ef6", which suggests some common problems may be in play, like a GetAll that loads the entire table, and/or eager loading of large fields whether they're needed or not. It's not as helpful as actual code, but right now that's the most useful information